# example of running xsl file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to know the problem of how to run xsl file in Eclipse.
I use jdk 1.6 with Eclipse platform. In fact, I want to extract a subset of XML file using XSL because of large size of xml document. I'm only interested in a subset of xml file.

Answer (score 3):

- You can install the [WTP Project](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) (contains the [XSL Tools](http://wiki.eclipse.org/XSLT_Project)), which will allow you to right click on a xsl file and 'run' it.
- You could use the [Ant XSLT Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what the problem you are having but you can right click on your xsl file in eclipse and choose "Run As" XSL Transformation and give it the xml you want.

You can also debug and check in the result view what's going on.

Comment: for this, you will need a plugin, like the web tools platform.
I don't think there is a "run As XSL Transformation" option in the 'normal' eclipse.